# Trying to interperet query url

Tags: search, json

I'm trying to interpret a query url and it's the last bit that I don't understand... What is "1":1033}  Additionally.. what does #Default= do?

```
https://Companycom.sharepoint.com/demo-search/SitePages/Home.aspx?PageView=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage#Default={"k":"","r":[{"n":"RefinableString14","t":["\"ǂǂ506f7765722047656e65726174696f6e\""],"o":"OR","k":false,"m":{"\"ǂǂ506f7765722047656e65726174696f6e\"":"Power Generation"}}],"l":1033}
```

Comment: 1033 is "en-us" language code

Comment: I've edited my question.  In addition, what does #Default= do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a Language Identifier in SharePoint.

1033 is LCID for English(United States).

You can read more about Language identifiers using below link:

1. [Language identifiers and OptionState Id values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2016/language-identifiers-and-optionstate-id-values-in-office-2016).

I am not totally sure about the `#Default=` part. But I think when you add some refinement filters and tokens then SharePoint automatically adds those in the query url.

You can read more about it using below link:

1. [Interpret Search with refiners url query string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193066/interpret-search-with-refiners-url-query-string).

Comment: I've edited my question Ganesh.. Can you take a quick look.  Cheers!

Comment: Do you have any search web parts on this page?

Comment: Yes.  SearchBox, Refinement Panel, and Search Results webparts.

Comment: `"r"` part shows the refinement filters,  `"n":"RefinableString14"` shows that you are refining on the field `RefinableString14` and `"t":["\"ǂǂ506f7765722047656e65726174696f6e\""]` shows the refinement token.