# How to pass refiners in query string?

Tags: search-results, refiner, refinement-panel

I would like to pass a refiner value from one page to the search page using query string. The refiner's name is: services.

How do I construct the query string?

I found this, but it does not make any sense to me: [Interpret Search with refiners url query string](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193066/interpret-search-with-refiners-url-query-string)

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://www.eliostruyf.com/part-5-search-refiner-control-methods-explained)?

Answer (score 1):

This is the anatomy of the json url that is searching via keyword and refiner:

```
http://your-site/Search/Pages/Results.aspx#Default={"k":"custom refiner","r":[{"n":"FileType","t":["equals(\"docx\")","equals(\"doc\")","equals(\"docm\")","equals(\"dot\")","equals(\"nws\")","equals(\"dotx\")"],"o":"or","k":false,"m":null},{"n":"DisplayAuthor","t":["\"ǂǂ456c696f20537472757966\""],"o":"and","k":false,"m":null}]}
```

Where:

> k: keyword; r: refinement filter; n: refiner name; t: refiner tokens;
>   o: operator (and, or); k: use KQL (Boolean); m: this is the token to
>   display value map. It's used when a custom refinement value (textbox)
>   is used. This stores the value that you inserted, to visualize it in
>   the refiner. Example: "m":{"equals(\"Item Value Text Box\")":"Item
>   Value Text Box"}

The url in the browser will be url encoded.  You must use a tool like:

https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

To decode your URL

Answer (score 0):

Use https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ to decode your URL and add custom filters :

k: keyword; r: refinement filter; n: refiner name; t: refiner tokens; o: operator (and, or); k: use KQL (Boolean); m: this is the token to display value map. It's used when a custom refinement value (textbox) is used. This stores the value that you inserted, to visualize it in the refiner. Example: "m":{"equals("Item Value Text Box")":"Item Value Text Box"}

Final URL will be :

[https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/Yoursite/Pages/Custom.aspx#Default={%22k%22:%22search%20keyword%22,%22r%22:[{%22n%22:%22RefinableString02%22,%22t%22:[%22equals(\%22refiner%20value\%22)%22],%22o%22:%22and%22,%22k%22:false,%22m%22:null}],%22l%22:2057}](https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/Yoursite/Pages/Custom.aspx#Default=%7B%22k%22:%22search%20keyword%22,%22r%22:%5B%7B%22n%22:%22RefinableString02%22,%22t%22:%5B%22equals(%5C%22refiner%20value%5C%22)%22%5D,%22o%22:%22and%22,%22k%22:false,%22m%22:null%7D%5D,%22l%22:2057%7D)

From decoding in https://www.url-encode-decode.com/ ,  it will be like :

[https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/Yoursite/Pages/Custom.aspx#Default={"k":"search](https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/Yoursite/Pages/Custom.aspx#Default=%7B%22k%22:%22search) keyword","r":[{"n":"RefinableString02","t":["equals("refiner value")"],"o":"and","k":false,"m":null}],"l":2057}