# Is there a way to use refiners to call a "standard" search result page from a custom query?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, search-results, query

Semi-novice here.  When one sees people using FilterField1 and FilterValue1, they are executing a query against a library, with the user seeing the results in the standard library view.

Is there a similar technique where I can present a user with a number of choices on a custom html form along with a regular search box component, then use those choices to narrow down (filter) the results from a search, then show them on my regular search results page?

edit:  I noticed [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/how-to-pass-refiners-in-query-string) that there is a way to pass refiners to a search.  Do I have to used managed properties (like RefinableString00), or is there a way to search directly against column names not mapped to managed properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, we suggest you use the “Advanced Search” page where end-users can apply some restrictions to their search phrase:

[image]

In addition to the default properties, you can also add custom property filters via editing "Advanced Search" web part.

More information for your reference:

https://searchexplained.com/configuring-advanced-search-in-sharepoint-2013-and-2016/

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/05/add-custom-properties-to-advanced-search.html

Comment: Thank you for this Julie!  This seems very close to what I'm looking for, so I'm glad it's at least possible this way.  Is there any way to make a custom form with these options already displayed (with check boxes next to each, for example), and then submit it to the normal search?  Would I have to essentially make my own control to do that?  What I'm trying to avoid is forcing the user to click the '+' sign next to each option to add it one by one, but rather have them all shown when first coming to the page.

Comment: Currently there is no OOB custom form except advanced search page, and you may need to create the page with code.